# Hiding UITableViewCells crashes when bringing them back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table with custom tableview cells which have a UISwitch on them.  When I tap the switch of what I call a "parent" cell, it's "children" cells are to disappear from the table.  When I tap the switch again, it's children come back.

I have this working perfectly by having the switch set an "enabled" flag in the underlying data model objects (the children).  Note, the children and parents are all of the same type, and part of the same array.  The heightForRowAtIndexPath method checks to see if the model object at the indexPath is a child and if it is and if it's disabled, it returns 0 otherwise it returns the proper not-hidden cell height (44).

I wanted to animate the hiding and showing of the children cells so I know I need to call `.beginUpdates()` and `.endUpdates()` on the tableView but I don't know where to do so.

When I put these in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, just before returning the configured, dequeued cell, it works when I hide cells but crashes when I try to bring them back.  The error text is below.

It seems that by setting the height to 0 the cells no longer exist and the indexes are messed up.  Does anyone know what I should be looking to do to remedy this?

Thanks!

Error text:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 19 beyond bounds [0 .. 18]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe7b9b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111ca0deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd5f514 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001109df87a -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 4765
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000110a11fa8 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001109fa599 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 218
    6   UIKit                               0x000000011096ba3b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
    7   QuartzCore                          0x000000011584e36a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000115842bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000115842a4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    10  QuartzCore                          0x00000001158371d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00000001158649f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000115865154 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fda7457 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fda73c7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd9d01b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd9c918 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115301ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001108be99e UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  MyApp            0x000000010f82284d main + 109
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001127cc92d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: You are indexing beyond the end of your array - possibly a simple loop error or an error in `numberOfRowsInSection` - please show the code that causes the exception

Comment: There are something wrong with the data model would you show us all the datasource code?

Comment: Rather than setting row heights to 0 I would calculate the right number of rows in `numberOfRowsInSection` and simply remove the hidden rows.  Animation is then simply calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`